# ¿Cómo integro autoload de composer con namespaces?

Tags: php, composer, namespace, autoload

esto empezando a practicar el uso de Composer en un proyecto muy basico para aprender su uso.
Me he encontrado con un problema a la hora de probar el autoload con los namespaces que le proporciono.
Esta es mi estructura de carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y también del árbol general:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\2024\Proyectos\Proyecto_Blog>tree
C:.
├───assets
│   ├───css
│   └───img
├───src
│   ├───Config
│   ├───Controllers
│   └───Models
├───vendor
│   └───composer
└───views
    ├───categorias
    ├───entradas
    └───usuarios
```

Yo quiero acceder desde mi index.php a las diferentes clases que tengo en **Controllers**, **Models**, etc.

Este es mi *index.php*

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use jorge\ProyectoBlog\Controllers\ControllerCategoria;
use jorge\ProyectoBlog\Controllers\ControllerUsuario;
use jorge\ProyectoBlog\Controllers\ControllerEntrada;
use jorge\ProyectoBlog\Models\ModelCategoria;
use jorge\ProyectoBlog\Config\Parametros;

$NameController = "jorge\ProyectoBlog\Controllers\\";
$NameController = $NameController . (($_GET['controller']) ?? Parametros::$CONTROLLER_DEFAULT);
$action = $_GET['action'] ?? Parametros::$ACTION_DEFAULT;

if (class_exists($NameController)) {
    $control = new $NameController();
    $control->$action();
} else {
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Y este es el error que me aparece al ejecutar:
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "jorge\ProyectoBlog\Config\Parametros" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\2024\Proyectos\Proyecto_Blog\index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\2024\Proyectos\Proyecto_Blog\index.php on line 11**

Y por si el fallo estuviera en la configuración del composer.json

```
{
    "name": "jorge/proyecto_blog",
    "description": "Proyecto para crear un blog",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "jorge\\ProyectoBlog\\Controllers\\": "src/Controllers",
            "jorge\\ProyectoBlog\\Models\\": "src/Models",
            "jorge\\ProyectoBlog\\Config\\": "src/Config"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Jorge"
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

También incluyo el contenido de mi Config/Parametros.php

```
<?php
namespace jorge\ProyectoBlog\Config;

class Parametros {
    public static $CONTROLLER_DEFAULT = 'Entrada';
    public static $ACTION_DEFAULT = 'index';
}
```

Comment: ¿En `Config` tienes un archivo llamado `Parametros.php`?

Comment: Si, tengo todos los ficheros en principio creados y con un par de lineas de codigo cada uno.

Comment: Deberías mostrar lo que hay en `Config` en la captura de pantalla. Y el contenido de `Parametros.php` **como texto**. No se ve lo que tienes declarado en ese archivo que es donde está el problema.

Comment: Ya he añadido la información sobre ```Parametros.php``` espero que puedas ayudarme. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Observa en primer lugar la diferencia al escribir los espacios de nombre. En `psr-4` los estás definiendo con una `J` mayúscula, mientras que en los archivos usas una `j` minúscula. ¿La carpeta se llama `Jorge` o se llama `jorge`? Como ya dije, coloca lo que es código **como texto** con copiar y pegar, no ayuda que compartas los bloques de código en capturas de pantalla.

Comment: Mis disculpas una vez más, ya he integrado el código correctamente.

Comment: De acuerdo.  Pero, ¿y lo otro? ¿Tu carpeta se llama `Jorge` o `jorge`? Según se llame, así debes declarar los espacios de nombre. Hay divergencia en tu código al respecto.

Comment: Mi carpeta se llama simplemete ```Proyecto_Blog``` esta está dentro de otra carpeta llamada ```Proyectos``` donde se encuentran otros proyectos diferentes.

Comment: Si has hecho cambios en tu archivo composer debes ejecutar el comando `composer dump-autoload` en la consola.

Comment: Aparte de eso, tienes un lío en tus nombres. Observa el mensaje de error: `C:\xampp\htdocs\2024\Proyectos\Proyecto_Blog\index.php:11`. Tu código esta buscando en una carpeta llamada **`Proyecto_Blog`**, sin embargo, en lo que nos muestras tú estás definiendo una carpeta que se llama `ProyectoBlog`. Muestra una captura del árbol de directorios completo y dinos cómo se llaman realmente tus archivos y carpetas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150952/discussion-between-jorch13-13-and-a-cedano).